# Chat server data model with delete each message feature in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to create a chat server one to one chat but i have to give delete option to both to delete her/his message one by one  .
I am using MySQL.

I already create a data model but i am not able to give delete feature.So i need a modular data model to implement this feature.

Please someone help me for the data model.

Answer (score 0):

I would use as following

```
message_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
from bigint(20) NOT NULL,
to bigint(20) NOT NULL,
message varchar(500),
state int(3) NOT NULL,
timestamp int(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("message_id"),
FOREIGN KEY ("from") REFERENCES user("userid") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
FOREIGN KEY ("to") REFERENCES user("userid") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Where state value determine the nature of message as follow,

```
0-> deleted by both user
1-> active message, default
2-> deleted by sender
3-> deleted by receiver
```

In my opinion, the code to implement logic plays the crucial role in this kind of model and works perfectly

Comment: in this model when i put a message i must have to put 2 entry for each message for each message there is a entry of sender and receiver my user id and one for sender is me  and receiver is friend  user Id then a able to see my all message where i am a receiver but the problem is when i chat with multiple friends and retrieve message for particular  friend i get  message of other friend also because i am put every message entry for me also